# How to override a later important in IE

Tags: css

I'm creating a online form use a web based OA system. In it I wrote the below code to set font to red, but it didn't work.

```
 .fnaOverlabel{
    color:red!important;
}
```

I debugged it and found out the reason is in the later part of the JSP file which loaded by the system,there is another css set the color to black, that one is from the system file which I can't modify. so is there a way to override it? Thx for any help.

Comment: did you used this class for label? for label try this`<label class="fnaOverlabel">test</label>` or can you add your html code here

Comment: And this is why `!important` should be avoided whenever possible. See: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/#when-should-important-be-used

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you may want to familiarize yourself with [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). The gist of it is that the more specific you are with a selector, the more weight that style will have.

You'll need to find out what is making that text black, and make a more specific selector than it, if you're unable to load in your CSS file later. This article has a good rundown on how [CSS Specificity Scores](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) can be calculated.

```
/* Your CSS*/
.fnaOverlabel{
    color:red !important;
}

/* System CSS */
#main-content .fnaOverlabel{
    color:black !important;
}
```

To override CSS like that, you would need a more specific selector, even just adding the tagname to the class selector would be enough:

```
#main-content span.fnaOverlabel {
    color: red !important;
}
```